# Soft Keyboard opens then closes in clicking edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview

I have a Recyclerview and one of the items has an edittext , but everytime i clcik on field to start typing the Soft Keyboard opens then closes right away. Has anyone experienced this before ?

Comment: I have the same problem right now, but ONLY if my EditText is the last item in my RecyclerView (I have  whole bunch of custom ViewHolders in it for different types of info)

Comment: For me it's for all items in the list

Comment: I would add a code sample to the post, this way people will be more likely to be able to help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe a little too late but I've just had this issue. I solved by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` to `YourActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`, like:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```